# Gmail Gadget Error 406 being thrown on osapi.http.post

Tags: google-apps-marketplace, gmail-contextual-gadgets

We have multiple marketplace Apps that use Gmail Contextual Gadgets.  These have been running for years successfully.

We are now noticing the following intermittent error being thrown when calling out to an external web server using open social osapi.http.post

**"{"id":"http.post","error":{"message":"Response not valid JSON","code":406}}"**

We have checked and there is nothing wrong with our server.  We can make the call directly to our server successfully without fail.

We can replicate the issue calling to multiple servers running different apps/gadgets.  The only commonality appears to be the use of osapi.http.post.

Here is the post

```
          osapi.http.post({
              'body': postdata,
              'href': serverUrl + 'iLinkStreamer.ashx?data=' + "" + setTimeStamp() + debugString,
              'format': 'json',
              'authz': 'signed',
              'noCache': true
            }).execute(displayStreamList);
```

which raises the 406 error as above

Has anybody else noticed this issue??  Not sure how we can address it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for a while and finally found the problem. I was also invoking external resources using `osapi.http.post`. I read the new documentation and found that there is a new way to do the same.

Check [this url](https://developers.google.com/gadgets/docs/remote-content) for more details, but the idea is that now you'll need to use [makeRequest API](https://developers.google.com/gadgets/docs/reference/#gadgets.io.makeRequest), it will look something like this:

```
var params = {};    
params[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.CONTENT_TYPE] = gadgets.io.ContentType.JSON;
params[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.AUTHORIZATION] = gadgets.io.AuthorizationType.SIGNED;
params[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.METHOD] = gadgets.io.MethodType.POST;
gadgets.io.makeRequest("https://your.backend.com", on_response_function, params);
...
def on_response_function(response){ ... }
```

I hope this helps someone.
I'm not sure if I'm the only one, but I never received a notification message that the previous API will be deprecated. :(

Comment: In 2011 they were talking about depreciate makeRequest... https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/opensocial-and-gadgets-spec/U5xz20_fHaA